# What is difference between isValid() and _isValid in moment.js?

Tags: javascript, html, momentjs

I want to check whether moment object is valid or not, so i used both isValid() and _isValid in different places. Both are giving same results. So i want to know purpose of using both.

Note: I know basic diff that one is function and other one is attribute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`isValid()` is [documented](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/) and so using it in prodution code is fine. It tells you whether the Moment instance contains a valid date/time.

`_isValid` is **not** documented and so using it in production code is a bad idea. It doesn't officially tell you anything. Its meaning could change, or it could disappear entirely, from one Moment to the next *(see what I did there? ;-) )*.

In general, in JavaScript, when you see a property name prefixed with `_` it means "this is internal, pretend you don't see it."

Comment: +1 for a solid answer and pun wizardry. It's a shame that `_isValid` might vanish without a Moment's notice, though...

Comment: Ha ha.. Thats cool answer man!! @Crowder. Even i always go with isValid(). Thank you